# how to add PSQL user For a Rails app that has full access but can't drop the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-restore

How to configure a PSQL v11.4 user that is not the superuser and does not own the database.
This user should have full access to create SQL objects and drop them, even
though they do not own the database, so they can not drop the database.
All sql/database objects exist on the PUBLIC schema.

So far I have tried:

```
CREATE USER app_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'foo_bar';
ALTER USER app_user NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE;
ALTER USER app_user VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database TO app_user;
```

When running Rails migrations I get the following error:
`remote: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for table schema_migrations`

Seems like the psql best practices is to have a role with privileges
set, then assign the user to be a member of that role. However because everything
is on the public schema all users/roles should have full access right? However
this line in the docs is throwing me off:

"The right to drop an object, or to alter its definition in any way, is not treated as a grantable privilege; it is inherent in the owner, and cannot be granted or revoked. (However, a similar effect can be obtained by granting or revoking membership in the role that owns the object; see below.) The owner implicitly has all grant options for the object, too."

from: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-grant.html

Also though because the database is being restored via the sudo user, objects
will be owned by the sudo user, however new objects could belong to the
app_user, is this an issue?

Comment: Now what is your problem? Or is your question only asking for opinions what is the One True Way to clone a database?

Comment: I think my exact issue is, how can I restore a database as a superuser, but then have a different user use that database with all privileges except dropping the database. Given the data base will be restored on to schema PUBLIC, maybe this is not a big issue at all.

Comment: Isn't there an application user that uses the original database? Why can't that user continue to use the restored database?

Comment: database is migrating to AWS RDS from another cloud provider and RDS has/allows for more complex permission levels

Comment: I have updated the question to be a bit more straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `CREATE` privilege on the database, and you need to `pg_dump` (or `pg_restore` with the `-x` and `-O` options, so that the restoring user becomes the object owner and no additional privileges are granted.

Some things, like certain extensions, event triggers or functions in untrusted languages (to name a few examples) require superuser rights to create them. Either avoid such objects or create them ahead of time and ignore the errors.

Comment: If I run the pg_restore, and have the connection info be the superuser, but have -x assigned to the app user, will the objets be owned by the app user and the restore will create extensions?

Comment: Creating the database and adding the extensions as the super user seems to have work, then I did a test restore as the app_user. Thanks!